# Problems connecting to WCF Service via NetNamedPipeBinding

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, channelfactory, netnamedpipebinding

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get a named pipe WCF service to work.
The service is in a seperate assembly from the executable.

The config looks like this:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netNamedPipeBinding>
        <binding name="NoSecurityIPC">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </netNamedPipeBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint name="internal"
        address="net.pipe://localhost/"
        binding="netNamedPipeBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="NoSecurityIPC"
        contract="TimeService.ITimeService" />
    </client>
    <services>
      <service name="TimeService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.pipe://localhost/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>            
        <endpoint name="internal"
          address="net.pipe://localhost/"
          binding="netNamedPipeBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="NoSecurityIPC"
          contract="TimeService.ITimeService" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I'm using a ChannelFactory to create a proxy to access the service host:

```
ServiceHost h = new ServiceHost(typeof(TimeService), new Uri("net.pipe://localhost/"));
h.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITimeService), new NetNamedPipeBinding("NoSecurityIPC"), "");
h.Open();

ChannelFactory<ITimeService> factory = new ChannelFactory<ITimeService>("internal");

ICpTimeService proxy = factory.CreateChannel();

using (proxy as IDisposable)
{                
    this.ds = proxy.LoadData();
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong when I create the ChannelFactory. It can't seem to find the "channel1" in the config. When I create my binding manually and pass it to the ChannelFactory constructor, the factory and the proxy are created but the call to the LoadData() fails (times out).

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

**EDIT: I edited above app.config to make sure both endpoints have the exact same data. That fixed my Channelfactory problem.
however, the call to the  service method as described above still times out.**

Comment: is it possible that LoadData really takes more than default time out period?

Comment: Nope, takes only a split second!

Comment: Enabling WCF tracing is always a good way to diagnose mysteries such as this; it would show exactly where the timeout is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the description of the problem as in the actual error message and such so it's hard to guess what your issue may be. Is it possible that you are attempting to run this under a non-admin account? I'm currently having problems getting WCF with NetNamedPipeBinding as a form of IPC under non-admin user accounts on Windows 7. Perhaps you are experiencing the same problem?